# Missing Space on Drive using Core Storage after Boot Camp Assistant Failure

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

Using Boot Camp Assistant, I started to create a 50 GB partition, but it hung on partitioning. After waiting about 30 minutes without the progress bar moving, I quit the Boot Camp Assistant, thinking I would be able to fix the partition either by using the Boot Camp Assistant or the Disk Utility. However, the partition doesn't appear in either. Instead, my drive has just become 50 GB smaller. Looking for other solutions, people were generally able to find the partition by using Terminal application commands, however I haven't even been able to do that. (Notice in Disk Utility, it says Macintosh HD is 441.65GB, but "Capacity" is 500.28GB):

[image]

I tried booting in Recovery mode and doing First Aid in the Disk Utility. This resulted in the same "All's Fine," but still haven't gotten my 50GB back. I spent all day clearing 100GB to make room for a Windows partition, and now in the Finder I'm down to 43GB :/.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: When you highlight the "Macintosh HD" volume in the Finder and select "Get Info" from the menu bar, what do you get for Capacity, Available and Used?

Comment: 441GB, 38.45GB, 402.53GB http://imgur.com/376Nopo

Comment: I do not have an answer. Even thought you have not posted your partition tables, I can see, from what you have posted, the problem is not one of partitioning. In the future I would avoid using Core Storage. This adds a level of complexity that is not necessary unless you have a Fusion drive or need encryption. Other users have posted this same problem and it always occurs when Core Storage is involved.

Comment: Ha! Thank you sir! You actually lead me to the solution. I'd never actually heard of Core Storage per se, that's just how my drive was set up by default. But in looking into it, I stumbled onto the "sudo diskutil cs revert [guid]" command, and got my 50GB back! Cheers!

Comment: You should post that as an answer. Or I could post the answer. If you do, I probably will edit your answer and add some of my own thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

The use of Core Storage seems to be a common denominator in problems similar to mine. I used the

```
sudo diskutil cs revert [Logical Volume guid]
```

command in the Terminal application to get rid of Core Storage, and then restarted. Presto! My missing GBs were returned.

> The above command can only be used if the command `diskutil cs list` shows the Logical Volume to be revertible. See the image included in the posted question for an example.