# Ran boot camp assistant, stalled out and didn’t create a second partition. How do I reclaim the space?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

Disk Utility.app displays my internal HDD "APPLE HDD" to be entirely taken up by "Macintosh HD" at 759.65 GB. Seeing as it’s a 1 TB hard drive, that’s a little disconcerting.

I also can’t reclaim the space using the partition tool, because there’s no partition to remove.

How do I fix this? Do I need to do a fresh install or reformat or something?

EDIT: Found the answer to it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238267/missing-space-on-drive-using-core-storage-after-boot-camp-assistant-failure?rq=1)

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Comment: You could do that as well.